# Automatically paste an image in 2nd worksheet when pasted in 1st

Tags: excel, vba

I would like a user to paste an image into a worksheet and automatically have it pasted to a second worksheet.  I have found some VB code that gets me close, but can't figure out how to finish it.  The image will change from user to user, but I'd like the action to occur as soon as the user pastes the image into E4.

I found this code, which helps, but its is not automatic.

```
Sub InsertLogo2()
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim shtSheet As Worksheet

    strPath = "C:\GraphicFolder\PictureName.bmp"

    For Each shtSheet In Worksheets
        shtSheet.Activate
        Range("A1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert (strPath)
    Next shtSheet
    Set shtSheet = Nothing
End Sub
```

I'm new to VBA, so really struggling with this.

Thanks!

Comment: You want to use a [`Worksheet Change()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) event.

Comment: Use the second sheet's `Worksheet_Activate` event to check the first sheet for images and copy over any found.  Does the second sheet contain any other images?

Comment: @BruceWayne - pasting an image won't trigger that event.

Comment: @TimWilliams oh, I didn't realize that!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the second sheet's `Worksheet_Activate` event to check the first sheet for images and copy over any found.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

    Dim shp As Shape, n As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Do While Me.Shapes.Count > 0
        Me.Shapes(1).Delete
    Loop

    n = 1
    For Each shp In Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes
        shp.Copy
        Me.Paste
        With Me.Shapes(n)
            .Left = shp.Left
            .Top = shp.Top
        End With
        n = n + 1
    Next shp
    Me.Range("A1").Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Whether or not this would be suitable would depend on your exact use case.

Note - this could be irritating if your users have something in the clipboard they'd like to paste...